# Omitting field if one record is incorrect

Tags: sql-server-2008

My goal is for claims with only bofa withdrawels to be displayed. When i do my code it only gives me 2, or at work it gives me claim 110329100082 which has bofa w/ds but i only want claimnbr who's disputes are only bank of america. In the end all i want is:

CLAIMNbr
121104101432,
130101104813,
130202100467,
130326100004

Use Claim
    GO

```
SELECT A.ClaimNbr


FROM dbo.CCMSClaimCore A
 LEFT JOIN dbo.CCMSTransactionCore B
 ON A.ClaimNbr = B.ClaimNbr

WHERE A.Frdtyp IN('Counterfiet', 'Counterfeit', 'CardSecure')
  AND B.merchantNm = 'BKOFAMERICA%WITHDR%'
  OR A.ClaimTypCd = 'ATMWP'
```

Heres some code to put into db

```
CREATE TABLE CCMSClaimCore 
(
ClaimNbr  varchar(50) Not NUll,
ClaimTypCd varchar(8) Not Null,
FraudTyp varchar(15) Not Null,
)

INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES (110329100082,   'FATMD',    'CardSecure')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES (110330101000,   'FATMD',    'CardSecure')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES(121104101432,    'FATMD',    'Counterfeit')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES(130101104813,    'ATMWP',    'CardSecure')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES(130101109216,    'FATMD',    'Counterfiet')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES(130202100467,    'ATMWP',    'Counterfiet')
INSERT INTO CCMSClaimCore (ClaimNbr, ClaimTypCd, FraudTyp)
VALUES(130326100004,    'FATMD',    'CardSecure')

Create table CCMSTransactionCore
(
ClaimNbr varchar(12) Not null ,
DisputeNbr varchar(12) Not Null ,
MerchantNm varchar(50) Not Null
```

)

```
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(110329100082,    110329200082,   'BKOFAMERICA ATM 03/28 #000007450           WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(110329100082,    110329200083,   'MPX1            03/27 #000918793 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(110329100082,    110329200084,   'BKOFAMERICA ATM 03/28 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(110330101000,    110330201000,   'PNC             01/17 #300918765     WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(121104101432, 121104201432,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 01/06 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(121104101432, 121104201433,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 01/06 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130101104813, 130101104813,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 12/06 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130101109216, 130101207892,  'MPX1            03/27 #000918793 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130101109216, 130101207893,  'PNC         03/24 #300918765 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130101109216, 130101207894,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 03/06 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130202100467, 130202200467,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 02/14 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130202100467, 130202200468,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 02/14 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
INSERT INTO CCMSTransactionCore (ClaimNbr, DisputeNbr, MerchantNm)
VALUES(130326100004, 130326200004,  'BKOFAMERICA ATM 03/08 #000007450 WITHDRWL')
```

Comment: so ultimately i return a claim number 123456789 with 3 disputes in it. 11111111, 222222222,333333333 and the first two have BKOFAMERICA%WITHDR% and the third returns pnc bank but will still return the claim number bc the first 2 records are bank of america.

Comment: additionally the "other" bank can be any bank name not just pnc thats my dilemma

Comment: I have no idea what your question means (what are "w/d", "ba", "w.d.", "bofa"...?). The best thing you can do is post some sample data and show what output you expect. Ideally, post `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements that someone can copy and paste into SSMS to set up your test case immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying you would like claim numbers where the related table has BKOFAMERICA%WITHDR% as the merchant name and **only** BKOFAMERICA%WITHDR%.  If it has BOFA and, for example, PNC, then do not show that claim number, right?  Try this:

```
Use Claim
GO

;WITH BOFAOnlyClaims AS (
    SELECT  B.ClaimNbr
    FROM    dbo.CCMSTransactionCore B
    GROUP BY B.ClaimNbr
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN B.merchantNm = 'BKOFAMERICA%WITHDR%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) = 1
)
SELECT  A.ClaimNbr
FROM    dbo.CCMSClaimCore A
        JOIN BOFAOnlyClaims BOC ON A.ClaimNbr = BOC.ClaimNbr
WHERE   A.Frdtyp IN('Counterfiet', 'Counterfeit', 'CardSecure')
        OR A.ClaimTypCd = 'ATMWP';
```

Comment: I just didnt know how to properly put it into words as a question lol

Comment: I think this is working .. but i really want to understand how it works. can you please explain it to me or at least the with section. thanks

Comment: The "WITH" section (called a Common Table Expression or "CTE") is assigning either a 1 or 2 to each record in CCMSTransactionCore (via the case statement): 1 = BOFA, 2 = Anything else.  Then it only retains the records that have a max of 1 (via the HAVING clause), meaning the claim has BOFA but not anything else.  Hope this is clear, and I am glad it is working for you.